# Can Vim's ALE's ALERename rename a folder or file and update all project imports?

Tags: typescript, vim

VSCode does this. I figured Stack Overflow would be the best place for me to ask this.

I'm assuming that the function of refactoring the names of files and folders and the updating of ES6 imports come under TSServer's responsibilities; hence ALE should be able to support it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works in ALE, just put the cursor over `bar` in `import { foo } from 'bar';` and do a `:ALERename foobar`.

ALE will use the language server to find every place that import something from `bar` and rename to `foobar`